# Virtual (USB) COM ports on Windows 11 Home (Surface)

Tags: serial-port, usb-c, microsoft-surface

I have a device which communicates via emulated serial over a USB A/B (USB-B at the device itself, USB-A into a host computer). I have used it successfully on a Windows 10 laptop, but I also want to use it with a Surface Go 2 which is running Windows 11 Home and is only equipped with a USB-C port. I have a USB A-to-C adapter as shown below which allows for the physical connection, but nothing happens when I plug it in. My laptop is equipped with both USB-A and USB-C ports, so I tried the same arrangement into my laptop and nothing happened for the 'C' port as usually happens for the 'A' port. The adapter works - I've used it to transfer files by USB memory stick between the same laptop and tablet. If I look in Device Manager, I can see the virtual COM port on the Win-10 laptop (via USB-A), but COM ports don't even show up on the Win-11 Home tablet. I should also add that the laptop USB-C is Thunderbolt; when docked, the device can successfully communicate through a USB-A on the dock, but it seems the tablet doesn't do anything with the dock connection other than draw power.

To summarize:

- Laptop has USB-A and USB-C (Thunderbolt) ports, is running Windows 10 Pro. Windows shows COM ports in Device Manager; the serial-over-USB-A peripheral works either directly connected to USB-A port on the laptop or to a USB-A port on Thunderbolt dock, but not via USB-A-to-USB-C adapter.
- Surface Go 2 tablet has only USB-C port, is running Windows 11 Home. Device Manager does not show any COM ports; the serial-over-USB-A peripheral  doesn't work either via USB-A-to-USB-C adapter or via Thunderbolt dock. Is there any way to get the peripheral to work on this tablet?

Has virtual COM been dropped from Windows 11? Is there something different going on in USB-C that prevents a virtual COM port even where supported over USB-A? Is there any limitation in Home edition?

[image]

Comment: A proper USB-C **hub** should work, one with USB-A ports, of course. The adapter shown may work for some devices but not all. Such adapters aren't part of the USB specifications and many people even think they're dangerous.